# Traverse using macros in STL

Tags: c++, macros, stl

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    map<string, int> M; 
    int r = 0; 
    tr(M, it) //this line is causing trouble
    { 
        r += it->second; 
    }  
}
```

What header file or preprocessor command do I need to enter to run.

Comment: That's not a macro that's part of the C++ standard; someone else devised it and you'll need to find the relevant header on your system, or write the code out longhand, or reinvent that particular wheel (which looks a bit squarish, or maybe just irregular).

Comment: What's the exact trouble that line causes anyway?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: there isn't a function `tr` available and there's a syntax error because there isn't a semi-colon after the call, and there isn't a declaration of `it`, so the code doesn't compile for multiple reasons.

Comment: That's still not an *exact* error message. My remark was intended for the author, who's posting lacks any precise error information, not for you, Jonathan.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try use a macro, just write the loop out properly. In C++11, it's almost as simple as the macro would be:

```
for (auto const & pair : M) {
    r += pair.second;
}
```

Historically, it wasn't much more verbose:

```
for (map<string, int>::const_iterator it = M.begin(); it != M.end(); ++it) {
    r += it->second;
}
```

If you really wanted such an evil macro, then you'd need C++11 (or a compiler-specific extension) in order to deduce the iterator type; and if you have C++11, then just use a range-style loop.